# Delete a word from an array

Tags: arrays, c

In this program you can add, print and delete words. I have an issue with the `delete()` function.
For example if I add the following words: `coconut`, `mango`, `banana`, `apple`. If I want to delete `mango` it deletes `mango` and then changes `apple` to `banana`, so the results I get after deleting is `coconut`, `banana`, `banana`. What am I doing wrong here? Do not change much from the original code, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 20

void add(char word[][MAX], int *nrOfWords);
void printWord(char word[][MAX], int nrOfWords);
void delete(char word[][MAX], int *nrOfWords);

int main() {
    char word[10][MAX];
    int nrOfWords = 0, choice; 

    while (1) {
        printf("(1)add word(2)print words(3)delete: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {     
          case 1:
            add(word, &nrOfWords);
            break;
          case 2:
            printWord(word, nrOfWords);
            break;
          case 3:
            delete(word, &nrOfWords);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void add(char word[][MAX], int *nrOfWords) {
    while (*nrOfWords < 10) {
        printf("Add word: ");
        scanf("%s%*c", &word[*nrOfWords]); 

        if (strcmp(word[*nrOfWords], "q") == 0)
            break;
        (*nrOfWords)++;
    }
}

void printWord(char word[][MAX], int nrOfWords) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nrOfWords; i++) {
        printf("%s, ", word[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void delete(char word[][MAX], int *nrOfWords) {
    char deleteWord[MAX];

    while (1) {
        printf("Word to delete:");
        scanf("%s%*c", &deleteWord);
        if (strcmp(deleteWord, "q") == 0)
            break;    
        for (int i = 0; i < *nrOfWords - 1; i++)
            if (strcmp(word[i], deleteWord) == 0) {
                strcpy(word[i], word[i + 1]);     
                (*nrOfWords)--;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with delete is that after deleting a word, it needs to move *all* of the words that follow it forward to close the gap.  But in the posted code, it only moves the word that immediately follows it.  It's also stopping prematurely when looking for the word, preventing it from finding the word if it's the last one.

Additionally, the `scanf` calls that read a word are passing the wrong argument type.  They need to pass `char *` values.  This results in compile-time warnings (make sure you have warnings enabled, then fix them).

The first incorrect `scanf` call is in `add`.  It should be:

```
scanf("%s%*c", word[*nrOfWords]);
```

I.e., remove the `&`.

The second incorrect `scanf` call is in `delete`, where the logic error was.  Here's a corrected version of the `delete` function:

```
void delete(char word[][MAX],int *nrOfWords){
    char deleteWord[MAX];
    while(1){
        printf("Word to delete:");
        scanf("%s%*c",deleteWord);
        if(strcmp(deleteWord,"q")==0)break;
        for(int i=0; i<*nrOfWords; i++) {
            if(strcmp(word[i],deleteWord)==0){
                (*nrOfWords)--;
                for (int j=i; j<*nrOfWords; j++) {
                    strcpy(word[j],word[j+1]);
                }
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows any word to be deleted, and copies *all* following words (if any) down one.

Comment: There is a problem in the `for(int i=0; i<*nrOfWords; i++)` loop: you should decrement `i` after removing a matching word so the next word can be tested too. As coded, successive identical words are not deleted completely.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks, good point.  I added the decrement of `i` so that it will remove all matching words, including consecutive ones.  A more efficient version would check for matches while moving the entries, running in linear time, but OP didn't want too much of a departure from the original, and I'm assuming duplicates aren't going to be common.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the matching word from the array, you must shift all remaining words down one position.  This can be done with a nested loop:

```
void delete(char word[][MAX], int *nrOfWords) {
    char deleteWord[MAX];

    for (;;) {
        printf("Word to delete:");
        if (scanf("%19s%*c", deleteWord) != 1 || !strcmp(deleteWord, "q"))
            break;    
        for (int i = 0; i < *nrOfWords;) {
            if (strcmp(word[i], deleteWord) == 0) {
                (*nrOfWords)--;
                for (int j = i; j < *nrOfWords; j++) {
                    strcpy(word[j], word[j + 1]);
                }
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note how `i` is only incremented if `word[i]` does not match `deleteWord`, otherwise the following word would be skipped in the scan.

The above approach is not efficient for large arrays with many duplicates.  Here is an alternative with fewer element moves:

```
void delete(char word[][MAX], int *nrOfWords) {
    char deleteWord[MAX];

    for (;;) {
        int i, j;

        printf("Word to delete:");
        if (scanf("%19s%*c", deleteWord) != 1 || !strcmp(deleteWord, "q"))
            break;    
        for (i = j = 0; i < *nrOfWords; i++) {
            if (strcmp(word[i], deleteWord) != 0) {
                if (i != j) {
                    strcpy(word[j], word[i]);
                }
                j++
            }
        }
        *nrOfWords = j;
    }
}
```